# How to encode pallet id & call id and then re-encode to a real Call

Tags: polkadot

I am able to decode a `Call` into `pallet id` and `call id` using below code

```
let (pallet_idx, call_idx): (u8, u8) = call
                .using_encoded(|mut bytes| Decode::decode(&mut bytes))
                .expect(
                    "decode input is output of Call encode; Call guaranteed to have two enums; qed",
                );
```

How can I build a `Call` back using pallet id and call id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
let bytes: Vec<u8> = (pallet_idx, call_idx).encode();
let call: Call = Decode::decode::<Call>(&mut &bytes);
```

For these kinds of questions, reviewing how [SCALE codec](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/scale-codec/) works is helpful, and then realizing that all types are just bytes, and can be arbitrarily passed back and forth from encoding and decoding.